# How to use MySql SUM() on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling with MySql SUM() function . For example , I have a table called `my_table` with columns('id','price_1','price_2') . I know this table is not following 1st normalization . But I need to just to demonstrate what I am in need . I want to select like this .

```
SELECT SUM({price_1 if price_2 is null}) GROUP BY `id`
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you need sum of `price_2` from only those rows where `price_1` is null or whether you need to have sum of from all rows so that `price_1` is used unless `price_2` is non-null, in which case it is to be included in sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(price_2,price_1)) as TotalPrice
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY `id`
```

`COALESCE` will take `price_1` if `price_2` is `NULL`. i.e., `COALESCE` will return the first parameter which is not `NULL`.

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e736b/1)

If you want to find the sum of `price_1` when all the `price_2` are `NULL`. Then:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(price_2),SUM(price_1)) as TotalPrice
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY `id`
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e736b/2)